# Avoid outline of button when clicked

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

The gear button below launches a modal window. when the modal is closed. An outline, like the one you see in the screenshot, appears. How do I avoid this?

[image]

Tried this, but didn't work

```css
.sticky-settings a:focus
{
    border: none;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set `outline: none` not `border: none`.

```
.sticky-settings a:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
.sticky-settings a:focus
{
    outline: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an `outline` property set on your button by default (it's a default browser property).

Overriding this property in your css will solve this.

```
.sticky-settings a:focus
{
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: @user48234: no problem at all :)